# How to do the bode plot for this function without Matlab?

Tags: control, control-system, bode-plot

I want to plot the bode diagram without any software for

$$G(s)=\frac{(s-2)}{(s^2+4s+15)(s+2)}$$

I do not know how to deal with the factor of \$s-2\$
I will be appreciate if someone can show me your working for the function rearrangement bit.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, The title "Hi guys, can anyone tell me ...?" of your question is a bit off I think, you could be a bit more formal.

Comment: @chloequin did you try actually replacing \$s\$ by \$j \omega\$ to follow the example you have? Once you have that it should be easy to plot the magnitude  \$|H(j \omega)|\$

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=find+poles++%28s-2%29%2F%28%28s%5E2%2B2s%2B17%29%28s%2B3%29%29

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=find+zeros++%28s-2%29%2F%28%28s%5E2%2B2s%2B17%29%28s%2B3%29%29

Answer (score 3):

When you have such transfer function (TF), it is good, in my opinion, to rewrite it in a *low-entropy* format in which poles and zeroes explicitly appear. For instance, you can see that this TF is made of a second-order TF cascaded with that of a zero and a pole located at the same position. The pole and the zero cancel each others in magnitude. Therefore, the magnitude response is that of a second-order TF: flat then going down with a -2-slope. We will see the phase later on.

Let's reformat this equation:

[image]

From here, you see a dc gain (actually an attenuation), then a normalized second-order polynomial and, finally, the pole and the zero. The negative sign in the zero indicates that it is in the right half-plane: this is a RHP zero whose magnitude is that of a classical zero but it lags the phase (like a pole would) rather than leading it. So the goal is to factor the whole thing as follows:

[image]

If you do the maths ok, you should find:

[image]

So you have a straight line starting at -23.5 dB in the magnitude plot, flat until 3.9 rd/s, then a slight peak occurs (\$Q\$ is almost 1) followed by a -2-slope (-40 dB per decade). As I said, the pole and the RHP zero are both coincident and neutralize each other in magnitude. The phase will start from 180° (you have an inversion) and will asymptotically hit 0°. The pace at which the phase drops depends on \$Q\$ and it should be rather smooth with 1. Then, the pole and zero phase will now cumulate (remember, this is a RHP zero) and prolong the phase drop from 0° to -180°. The plot could look like this:

[image]

Without the pole-zero pair, the phase of the inverting second-order network would cross 90° at the resonance and further go down to 0°. Adding the pole-zero pair positioned before the resonance will distort this value and I have indicated an approximate point (it's 3.08 rd/s) at which crossing occurs but for a hand-drawn response it should be good enough. Finally, using Mathcad, you obtain the exact shape:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several on-line tools available to perform a Bode plot. Here is a good one, because it also plots the asymptotic approximation.

http://www.onmyphd.com/?p=bode.plot.online.generator

A step-by-step explanation is provided there as well, under

http://www.onmyphd.com/?p=bode.plot

You can also just search for on-line plotting tools, if that is all you need to do:

https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=online+bode+plot&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

If you know what poles and zeros are, you can read them directly from the expression for H(s). In the case of a second-order section, you will have to break it into roots. The above on-line tool also deals with the case of conjugate pairs.

Comment: Hmm, not really an answer to the question I think, and short enough to be a comment.

Comment: By "without Matlab" he probably means without the use of any software, so The first part of your answer doesn't really help (the links).

Comment: @Vinzent He is asking to plot without Matlab. This does just that. If you want to answer go ahead. If you like long answers, go ahead. If he doesn't like the answer, he can comment and we/I can help further.

Comment: @jDAQ The first link provided by P2000 actually goes to great lengths to talk about ***how*** to do it, by hand. So it **is** a helpful link, I think. But it should just be a comment in my opinion.

Comment: @jonk well he said "There are several on-line tools available..." and I assumed it was just an online plotting (without Matlab). I disagree that it "goes to great lengths" on how to do it, unless you check the other contents on their website. And yes, I agree that it would be better as a comment, considering that questions on how to hand draw bode plots have definitely been answered before and this would be just a duplicate.

Comment: @jDAQ Well, perhaps I over-spoke when I said "great." But I think it was more than adequate and it includes some step-by-step applets to help "get a feel" for things, too, so that you can sharpen your hand skills better. I actually liked it. But perhaps I haven't seen a still better site.

Answer (score 0):

If you must draw it and show how you got it in details use Excel or other spreadsheet program that knows complex numbers. Make one column of cells which has the log of the frequency with linear steps, let another column be the actual frequency and the next two the gain in dB and the phase. Sort the columns so that frequency, gain and phase are adjacent for rectangular plot area. Make the needed imtermediate calculation columns outside the graph data area to keep the formulas shorter.

Comment: By "without Matlab" he probably means without the use of any software, like hand drawing it.

Comment: The classic technique for a system which has distant enough zeros and poles is well presented in control theory books. It was in a good use say 50 years ago. After computers came generally available practical plotting became much more accurate and easier.

Comment: I agree that it is not practical to hand draw it, but assuming that by "without Matlab" means any other software is an answer doesn't seem reasonable either. Otherwise the OP would just make a shopping question "what software to use for plotting bode plots other than Matlab"